# Getting a random object from NSSet doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsset

Why am I not getting a random value from the list?

If I set the color manually like `[UIColor redColor]` just work fine.

```
- (id) init
 {
    self.color = [self randomColor]; //This doesn't work
    self.color = [UIColor someColor]; //This works
 }

- (UIColor *) randomColor {
    NSSet *colors = [NSSet setWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor orangeColor], nil];
    return [colors anyObject];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-anyObject does not return a random object. It's just difficult to predict which object it will return (most likely it's either the most efficient one to return, or the simplest to implement internally).

Comment: It returns an object of the list, but its not applying the color.

Comment: You were right, it was returning always the same color (green, the same as the object so i can't figure it out). I will randomize it with a function thx